# How to properly use VAOs?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm just getting started with OpenGL, and I'm trying to use only 3.x and above features. One thing I do not understand is VAOs.

I do understand that a VAO encapsulates rendering state, so i can call all the setup functions prior to the render loop and then just bind the VAO to get back all the state changes made in the setup. What I am not clear on is how I should lay out my data. Should I have each model in the scene get it's own VAO, or should I use a few VAOs and bind the VBOs of multiple models to it (which I have read is more efficient)?

Answer (score -1):

VAO encapsulates bound buffed and vertex attributes in it. So if you need to bind different buffer and set up different attributes for draw call, then you should assign different VAO to that.